# The number $\binom{8}{4}$ is equal to the number of subsets of size 4 of the set $\{1, \dots, 8\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, binomial-coefficients

I was asked to proof if is true and give a counter example if it is false.

However I prefer True.
since all the numbers 1-8 insides the brackets are in the sets.

I'm I correct?

Comment: This is true, nearly by definition. I don't see what's there to prove, because order does not matter for a subset, the subset $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is the same as $\{ 4,3,2,1\}$ although they may be picked in different order. When the order does not matter, we are simply "choosing" objects as opposed to "permuting" them. The answer in this case is therefore true.

Comment: What is your definition of $\binom{n}{m}$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an intuitive proof:

For the first element in the subset, we have $8$ choices of which element to include. Because sets do not repeat elements, for the second element, we have $(8-1)$ choices, and for the third $(8-2)$, and for the fourth, $(8-3)$. This gives us the value $\frac{8!}{(8-4)!}$ as the number of possible subsets. However, because sets are unordered, we overcounted. Because each subset is of four elements, and the number of permutations of four elemetns is $4!$, we have $4!$ times the true number of subsets. Thus, the final number is $\frac{8!}{4!(8-4)!}$, which is by definition $\binom{8}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is true.

We know that $$ \binom84 = \frac{8\times 7 \times 6 \times 5}{4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1} $$

$8\times 7 \times 6 \times 5$ is the number of ways to pick 4 distinct numbers out of 8 distinct numbers one by one, because you have 8 choices when you pick the first number, then 7 choices when picking the second, and so on.

In this way, each combination of 4 numbers is counted $4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$ times, because there are $4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$ ways to permute 4 distinct numbers.

Hence the result.